# Ограничение на установку android-приложения

Tags: android-sdk, android

Имеются следующие вопросы:
1. Можно ли как-то ограничить установку на, например, телефоны с `API` ниже 15?
Вопрос заключается не в том, чтобы запретить вывод в поиске по Маркету, а именно запрет на установку. То есть, имея установочный файл, user не сможет установить его из-за низкой версии.
2. Можно ли ограничить установку по разрешению экрана? Например, пользователям с `mdpi`  и `ldpi` запретить установку уже имеющегося apk-файла?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно.

1. Для ограничения по уровню API в манифесте есть тег `uses-sdk` с атрибутом `android:minSdkVersion` ([документация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html))

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="15"
       android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
   ```
2. Для ограничения по разрешению экрана ([документация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)):

   ```
   <manifest ... >
   <compatible-screens>
   <!-- all small size screens -->
   <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
   <!-- all normal size screens -->
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
   </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
   ...
   <application>
    </manifest>
   ```

Comment: благодарю за ответ! Правильно ли я понимаю, что, если я добавлю эти строчки в Манифест, то пользователь не сможет установить приложение, даже если у него есть установочный файл на телефоне?

Comment: @user186295, да, если телефон не будет соответствовать заявленным в манифесте требованиям. А в маркете будет написано "что ваша модель телефона не поддерживается".